# onClick not rendering a different react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've created a SocialShare component which I want to render when Share button is clicked on any of my other components.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Share, Button} from 'react-native';

export class SocialShare extends Component {

  onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React',
      });

      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (

      this.onShare()

      );
  }
}
```

This is how I am calling this component from another component:

```
<View>
    <Button onClick={() => this.onShareButtonClick()}>Button</Button>
         {this.state.showShareComponent ?
             <SocialShare /> :
             null
         }
</View>
```

onShareButtonClick function:

```
onShareButtonClick(){        
        this.setState({
            showShareComponent: !this.state.showShareComponent,
        })
    }
```

On click of button, this is the error I am getting:

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in SocialShare
```

What's wrong with my code?

Edit:
As per suggestions, modified my SocialShare class to this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Share, Button} from 'react-native';

export class SocialShare extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        asyncCompleted: false,
    };
  }
  onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React',
      }).then(
        this.setState({asyncCompleted: true})
      );



      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {

        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };


  render() {
    return (

      <View>
      {this.state.asyncCompleted ? this.onShare() : null}
      </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Now, nothing happens on click of button from my other class.

Comment: don't perform a side effect in render method, use ```componentDidMount``` instead

Comment: Also, it's recommended to use the callback syntax when setting state based on current state values: `this.setState(prevState => ({ showShareComponent: !prevState.showShareComponent }))`. (Not a fix for your question though)

Comment: Basically, you're not rendering anything in the `SocialShare` component; you're only calling the `Share.share` which you can do on the Button's click.

Comment: Even this does not work:
```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
      {this.onShare()}
      </View>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like the main issue is that your render method is attempting to render a promise directly, as would be returned by the asynchronous `onShare()` method. Instead, you should make the asynchronous code update the component's state, which can then trigger a render that will be based on this state value rather than the direct output of `onShare()`

Comment: No not really - I'm not sure what you're actually trying to render. But I think this should give you enough of a clue to figure out the rest for yourself. As I said, the basic problem is that you are trying to render a promise object directory. (Async methods return a promise behind the scenes.)

Comment: Added this constructor:
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        asyncCompleted: false,
    };
  }

Added this in the try block:
const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React',
      }).then(
        this.setState({asyncCompleted: true})
      );

Modified render:
render() {
    return (

      <View>
      {this.state.asyncCompleted ? this.onShare() : null}
      </View>
      );
  }

Now, nothing happens on click :(

Comment: Your update makes even less sense. You're still trying to render a method that returns a promise for some reason. Nothing in `onShare` looks like rendered output. Ask yourself what should actually be rendered after the share has completed. But it seems as though you want the `Share.share()` to be triggered by the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle here, as this would be triggered by the button click. Probably would be better if the button's click handler could trigger this directly in the same component though. All in all, this is a little confusing...